# Applying a 1D Convolution on a Tensor in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have a Tensor that represents a set of 1D signals, that are concatenated along the column axis. So say I have 300 1D signals that are of size 64. So [64x300]

I want to apply a smooth convolution / moving average kernel on it [0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2] on the GPU, but I am not sure exactly what is the API to do it. Can I be provided an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular `torch.nn.Conv1d` to do this.

### Inputs

In your case you have `1` channel (`1D`) with `300` timesteps (please [refer to documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170758) those values will be appropriately `C_in` and `L_in`).

So, for your input it would be (you need `1` there, **it cannot be squeezed!**):

```
import torch

inputs = torch.randn(64, 1, 300)
```

### Convolution

You need `torch.nn.Conv1d` with `kernel_size` equal to `5` (as indicated by your elements: `[0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2]`) and no `bias`. I assume your output has to be of the same size (`300`) so `2` elements have to be padded at the beginning and end. All of this gives us this module:

```
module = torch.nn.Conv1d(
    in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=5, padding=2, bias=False
)
```

Weights of this module (`0.2` values) can be specified like this:

```
module.weight.data = torch.full_like(module.weight.data, 0.2)
```

`torch.full_like` will work for kernel of any size in case you want other size than `5`.

Finally run it to average steps and you're done:

```
out = module(inputs)
```

### GPU

If you want to use `GPU` just cast your `module` and `inputs` like this:

```
inputs = inputs.cuda()
module = module.cuda()
```

See [CUDA documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html) for more information.